# Background image to fill background when browser fully opened, and crop when closed

Tags: html, css

I would like to use an image as the total window background when the browser window is fully open using any size display.

If the browser window is made more narrow, the left and right sides of the image should be cropped and a scrollbar should not be displayed.  `background-size: cover;` seems to get me close, but crops off the right side.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Use: background-position: center; to center the background image?

Comment: @FWrnr  I was so close!  Thank you

Comment: Great! :) I added the solution also as an answer (as I misused the comment system to give an answer).

Comment: Will select it in 7 minutes!  Thanks again.

Comment: @FWrnr  Please make sure you are okay with me editing your answer.

Comment: I made some minor improvements to your edit; I hope you agree with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body { 
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Centers the background image on the page.